# Weird wording in the "needs clarity" notice

Tags: bug

Following kulfy's advice I posted this bug report on meta.se (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341037/206420), but would like to keep **this** question for visibility (at least for a while)

---

The "needs clarity/details" notice contains the words

> ... the problem being solved.

This **should** read something like

> ... the problem needing a solution.

or just

> ... the problem.

[image]

I don't know if this wording is special to AU or sitewide and I should post this on Meta.SE .

Comment: Since the notices are network-wide, I'd encourage you to post on [meta.se] so that more eyes can see this. You can also post this as an answer to [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/468333) since I believe your question is  a feedback to the redesign.

Comment: Will do, @kulfy, thx